# Combining boolean checks with & doesn't "short-circuts"?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Series:

```
2013-09-30           None
2013-10-31           None
2013-11-30    1.47701e+06
2013-12-31    1.47701e+06
2014-01-31    1.47701e+06

Freq: M, Name: test_series, dtype: object
```

If I do:

`pd.notnull(test_series) & np.sign(test_series) == 1`

Why do I get an error:

`*** TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < int()`

Why doesn't the first check for `notnull` short-curcuits and the second check is not done at all when the Series elements are None?

Comment: I think pandas/numpy works with arrays, so use `&` one boolean mask with another boolean mask.

Answer (score 2):

I think not, because `&`, `|` works with booelan `Series`.

So it combine element-wise one `mask` from first condition with another `mask` by operator `&`.

```
#convert to numeric, if not possible get NaN
test_series = pd.to_numeric(test_series, errors='coerce')

mask1 = pd.notnull(test_series)
mask2 = np.sign(test_series) == 1
print (mask1)
2013-09-30    False
2013-10-31    False
2013-11-30     True
2013-12-31     True
2014-01-31     True
Name: test_series, dtype: bool

print (mask2)
2013-09-30    False
2013-10-31    False
2013-11-30     True
2013-12-31     True
2014-01-31     True
Name: test_series, dtype: bool

print (mask1 & mask2)
2013-09-30    False
2013-10-31    False
2013-11-30     True
2013-12-31     True
2014-01-31     True
Name: test_series, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Actually, just `test_series = pd.to_numeric(test_series, errors='coerce')` actually helps in this case. Because then np.sign() doesn't fail.

Comment: Hmmm, what return `print (np.sign([np.nan]))` for you? for me `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sign`.  So possible solution is `fillna` - `np.sign(test_series.fillna(0)) == 1`